# Continuous Random Packing Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I was stumped by this problem I found in a stats textbook. Here it is:

Consider the interval $(0, x)$ and suppose that we pack in this random unit intervals — whose left-hand points are all uniformly distributed over $(0, x-1)$. The interval is packed such that if the next random interval intersects any of the previous intervals it is disregarded and we look at the next random interval. The procedure is continued until there is no more room for additional intervals (i.e. all gaps between packed intervals are smaller than $1$).

Let $N(x)$ denote the number of unit intervals thus packed in $(0, x)$. Let $M(x) = \Bbb E[N(x)]$. Show that $M$ satisfies 
$$M(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x < 1\\
(\frac2{x-1})\int_0^{x-1}M(y)\,dy + 1,& x > 1\end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks! I’ve tried brute expansion of the integral, but I don’t want to bias anyone answering; feel that I’m missing some piece of intuition for simplification somewhere, like for giving an alternative formula for the expectation and that sort of thing.

Comment: You should include your attempts in the body of the question. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math symbols. Also see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @ThomasShelby OK, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$Denote $Y$ as the position (of the left end point) of the "first" unit interval. Consider the decomposition conditioning on $Y = y$ that splits the original $(0,x)$ into subsequent "left" and "right" intervals: $(0,y)$ and $(y+1,x)$.

\begin{align}
M(x) = \mathbb{E}[N(x)] &= \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} \frac1{x - 1} \mathbb{E}\left[N(x) \,\middle|~ Y = y\right] \dd{y} \\
&= \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} \frac1{x - 1} \big( 1 + M(y) + M(x-y-1) \big) \dd{y} 
\end{align}
where $\frac1{x-1}$ is the density for $Y$, the "$1+{}$" accounts for contribution to $M(x)$ by the first unit interval, and $M(y)$ is the contribution from the subsequent "left" interval $(0,y)$ whereas $M(x-y-1)$ is from the subsequent "right" interval $(y+1,x)$.

Pull the constant "$1+{}$" out, and make the change of variable for the "right" contribution (which expresses the symmetry between the left and the right):
\begin{align}
M(x) = \mathbb{E}[N(x)] &= \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} \frac1{x - 1} \mathbb{E}\left[N(x) \,\middle|~ Y = y\right] \dd{y} \\
&= 1 +  \frac1{x - 1} \left( \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} M(y)\dd{y} + \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} M(x-y-1) \dd{y} \right) \\
&= 1 +  \frac1{x - 1} \left( \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} M(y)\dd{y} + \int_{y' = x-1}^0 M(y') (-\mathrm{d}y') \right) &&\text{, where}~ y' = x-y-1 \\
&= 1 +  \frac2{x - 1} \int_{y = 0}^{x-1} M(y)\dd{y}
\end{align}
$Q.E.D.\endgroup$

Comment: Wonderfully clear and the comments were helpful as well, thank you very much!