# Reference for Renyi's parking problem

Tags: probability, reference-request

The Renyi parking problem is as follows:

For a number $x>0$ a random subinterval $I_1$ of $(0,x)$ of length $1$ is chosen. As next step we choose a random subinterval of $(0,x)\setminus I_1$ of length $1$. As third interval we choose a random subinterval of $(0,x)\setminus (I_1 \cup I_2)$ and so on, but the process stops when it is not longer possible to place an interval of length $1$.

Let $M(x)$ be the expected number of placed intervals in the procedure. According to [1] in the work [2] Renyi has shown that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{M(x)} x = \int_0^\infty \exp \left(-2 \int_0^x \frac{1- e^{-y}}{y}\text{d}y \right) \text{d}x$$

In [1] it is also mentioned that Renyi used a recursive representation for $M(x)$, which is presented in the answer to [The parking problem riddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376236/the-parking-problem-riddle) and in [Continuous Random Packing Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159341/continuous-random-packing-problem)

[1] *Renyi's Parking Problem Revisited*: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1781

[2] Rényi, Alfréd; *On a One-Dimensional Problem Concerning Random Space-Filling*,
Publ. Math. Inst. Hung. Acad. Sci. 3, 109–127 (1958)

**Requests**:

1. Is it possible to find a full-text version of [2] ? I found that it also appeard in "Select. Transl. Math. Stat. Probab." and there is the [google book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=de&id=TBwPAAAAIAAJ&dq=Selected%20Translations%20in%20Mathematical%20Statistics%20and%20Probability&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=one-dimensional) of that journal, but I cannot access it.
2. Is the proof to be found in a book or is there some monograph about this topic?
3. Is this the only proof of this statement or have other techniques been found in order to prove this?